# Loop in function and store different results per loop python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to store different results per loop in a list or even better straight into a dictionary.
So per loop I get different results due to the if statement criteria.

a:10
b:20
c:30

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

def cells_rows(x):
   for col_cells in worksheet.iter_cols(min_col=x.column, max_col=x.column, min_row=5):
       for cell2 in col_cells:
           if cell2.value is not None:
              rrr = cell2.value
              print(rrr)

workbook = load_workbook('testsheet.xlsx')
print(workbook.get_sheet_names())
worksheet =workbook.get_sheet_by_name('sheetname')

for row_cells in worksheet.iter_rows(min_row=4, max_row=4):
   for cell in row_cells:
      if cell.value == "ZONES":
         zones = cells_rows(cell)

      if cell.value == "DESCRIPTION":
         cells_rows(cell)
```

With this code I get all the values printed per loop. However if I use return instead of print I only get the first value. So I need either the ZONES values in one list and DESCRIPTION in another. Or even better both {ZONES:DESCRIPTION}.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know how to create list and add elements to it? You have to add to list right where you have the `print` now. Then you have to return the list, where? — After all loops. Good luck.

Comment: I have tried but did not work. Puts every single one into separate list. Not first condition result into one and second into another. Little hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Please share the code that *"puts every single one into separate list"*. We can help you correct it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @austin suggested, use a list. This list must be created outside of the for loop. Otherwise you will get separate lists.

```
def cells_rows(x):
    l = list()
   for col_cells in worksheet.iter_cols(min_col=x.column, max_col=x.column, min_row=5):
       for cell2 in col_cells:
           if cell2.value is not None:
              l.append(cell2.value)
```

Comment: Thank you but with the above I'm getting this pattern: [1], [1,2], [1,2,3]...and so on. Each of them on separate line. I'm trying to achieve is [1,2,3,4] and [a,b,c,d]. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Ok I put the return list inside the loop too. So once outside it worked. Thanks @Just learned it!